# Single setInterval for multiple elements, how to stop interval on specific element and not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

```
var intervalID = "";
if(intervalID){clearInterval(intervalID)}    
intervalID = setInterval(function(){

$('#parentDiv childsRequiringInterval').each(function(){
//do stuff
}); //each
}); // setinterval
```

I am currently instantiating multiple countdowntimers using JqueryKnob which is irrelevant. am updating countdowns using setInterval per second. Thing is, when ONE of the timers expire, and I need to 'unbind' it or cancel that specific instance of the setinterval for just that element, I can't. since I'll kill the setinterval of all timers.

have looked at couple other questions, one of which used an array for intervalIDs, but didn't pick up how to populate unique intervalIDs and maintain them. Since I'll be re-creating new timers whenever one expires for different content. (as my idea was to capture the position of each element and if it's in dom position [0] use that as intervalID, but I might inject a new timer when one expires.. Suggestions?

Comment: You can either set up several intervals (for each element), then cancel the target one, or create a mask which will be checked in the single function before 'doing stuff'. I'd prefer the second approach.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd recommend at least considering using `requestAnimationFrame` for this task.

Comment: @raina77ow, instead of applying a mask, I'd cache the selection in a variable, and `filter()` wich ones to keep, or use `not()` so keeping the item is default on return. `$countdowns = $countdowns.not(function(){ ... if(clocktimedOut) return true })`

Comment: Yes, of course, it's better to cache the selection - unless it's dynamic.